# Cannot stop repeating timer

Tags: ios, nstimer

So I'm using a repeating `NSTimer` to track the progress of my video player.  When it hits a certain time, the video is supposed to stop/pause and the timer is of course, supposed to  be invalidated as well.  Here's the code I planned to use to stop it:

```
- (void)stopPlayer{
    if (self.playerIsPlaying) {
        [self.player pause];
        self.playerIsPlaying = NO;
        self.inPause = NO;
        [self.timer invalidate]; //This is NOT the repeating timer
        self.timer = nil;
        NSLog(@"Invalidating tracker, timeInterval %f",self.tracker.timeInterval);
        [self.tracker invalidate]; //THIS IS THE REPEATING TIMER
        self.tracker = nil;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        self.restartArea.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.atEndOfVideo = YES;
    }];
}
```

But for some reason the video is paused, the timer is still going.  The logging statement `Invalidating tracker, timerInterval...` does show which means that line gets run and the timer also gets set to nil, but why is it still running?

I'm thinking it's because I scheduled this timer in a block where the `self` object gets set to an `unsafe_retained` reference.  Could this be the case?

Here's the block that is responsible for firing the timer:

```
__unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self.slider setProgress:0 animated:YES completion:^{
    [weakSelf.player play];
    weakSelf.timer = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
    weakSelf.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:weakSelf.clipLength target:weakSelf selector:@selector(stopPlayer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    weakSelf.playerIsPlaying = YES;
    [weakSelf fireTimer]; //Here's the line that fires my repeating `tracker` timer.
    return;
}];

- (void)fireTimer{
    NSLog(@"0.1s timer fired");
    self.tracker = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
    self.tracker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(trackProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the problem!
Turned out that the same timer got fired twice (idk why I was calling it once only)
but anyways, I added a line that prevented it from re-firing.

```
if(self.tracker){
    NSLog(@"Timer already fired");
}
else{
    self.tracker = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
    self.tracker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(trackProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the timer on the main thread?

```
- (void)fireTimer{
    NSLog(@"0.1s timer fired");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tracker = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
        self.tracker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(trackProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }];

}
```

Comment: I tried it but it's still going on and on and on :(